# Outlook email sort places selected email at bottom of screen

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007

In Microsoft outlook, I want to sort by subject to see all subjects related to the message I am reading. When I arrange by subject, the emails are sorted correctly, but the email I have selected always goes to the bottom of the window, requiring me to scroll down to view the emails below the selected email. I would like the selected email to start in the middle of the window so I can see similar subjects before and after the selected email.

Is there any way to accomplish this?